# One of the Heire-Borel lemmas states the following:

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

If a set is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then it is compact. However, what about a more abstract metric space $(X,d)$? Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space with a subset $A$ closed and bounded, then show that $A$ is compact.

Comment: The correct extension is closed and totally bounded, if I recall properly. It means that given any $\varepsilon>0$, there is a finite cover of $\varepsilon$-balls. I might have forgotten something, but I think this is correct.

Comment: Yes, if $(X,d)$ is a **complete** metric space then a subset $A$ is compact if and only if $A$ is closed and **totally bounded**. This an immediate consequence of two facts: 1. Since $A$ is closed, we have that $A$ is itself a complete metric space. 2. Any complete and totally bounded metric space is compact.

Answer (score 2):

If $(X,d)$ denotes a metric space then we can construct a metric $d'$ on $X$ by stating: $$d'(x,y)=\min(d(x,y),1)$$

This function can be shown to be a metric and induces the same topology as the original $d$.

However *every* subset of $X$ is bounded with respect to the constructed metric.

Comment: Sorry I didn't even notice your A before posting mine.....+1

Comment: Does closed and bounded imply totally bounded?

Comment: No. Note that $\mathbb R$ is bounded with respect to the metric $d(a,b)=\min(|a-b|,1)$ and is closed as well. But $\mathbb R$ is not totally bounded. In fact boundedness is not a topological property because it depends on the metric that is used (as shown in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

It is not true in general, the closed unit ball of an infinite dimensional Banach space is not compact

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest counterexample is the discrete metric [ $d(p,q)=1$ when $p\ne q$ ] on any infinite set $X.$ Then every subset of $X$ is bounded and open and closed, but only the finite subsets of $X$ are compact.